# Filter with Dates but keep the calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I would like to know what can you do in the following scenario:

Lets say I am filtering on a date in the `where` clause `(between eomonth(@StartDate) and eomonth(getdate()-1)`. I have a calculated column that is correct when I run the query without any filter, but the problem is that when I filter lets say `@StartDate = 06/30/2017` then the calculations will obviously change. Is there any way of doing this?

The calculated column is a windowing function.

Edited:

I have added a picture of the data. So I am using a windowing function to calculate the agentfourmonthperiod. You will see that it sums the units for that month and the 3 previous months. This I dont want to change when filtering. So the units and agentfourmonthperiod columns should stay exactly the same after filtering on the @StartDate. Please see data below:

[image]

I want to design an SSRS report that the user will be filtering on the @StartDate, but then it should show the calculation as it does when no filter in used.

Hope this makes sense. Otherwise I can add the code. Its just quite long though.

Code:

```
  WITH DATA
                AS
                (
                SELECT  
            EOMONTH(SubmissionDates.original_date_c) AS IntakeMonth,

            ProvincialArea.SAD_ProvMananger AS ProvManager,
            RegionalArea.SAD_RegMananger AS RegManager,
            SalesArea.SAD_SalesManager AS AreaSalesManager,

            ConsultantUserExt.name AS Consultant,

            COUNT(LeadsLink.LeadsID) OVER(PARTITION BY ConsultantUserExt.name, EOMONTH(SubmissionDates.original_date_c,0) ORDER BY EOMONTH(SubmissionDates.original_date_c,0)) AS Unit,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ConsultantUserExt.name, EOMONTH(SubmissionDates.original_date_c,0) ORDER BY EOMONTH(SubmissionDates.original_date_c,0)) AS rn

FROM Import.OobaApplication as Application

LEFT OUTER JOIN Import.OobaApplicant applicant ON application.ApplicationID = applicant.ApplicationID 
                AND applicant.PrincipleApplication = 'Y'

LEFT OUTER JOIN usr_userext_cstm ON Application.Consultant = usr_userext_cstm.comcorp_key_c
    or Application.Consultant = usr_userext_cstm.deal_maker_key_c
    or Application.Consultant = usr_userext_cstm.ops_key_c

LEFT OUTER JOIN usr_userext AS ConsultantUserExt ON usr_userext_cstm.id_c = ConsultantUserExt.id AND ConsultantUserExt.deleted = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN usr_userext_cstm AS ConsultantUserExtCstm on ConsultantUserExt.id = ConsultantUserExtCstm.id_c

LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.ProvincialArea AS ProvincialArea ON ConsultantUserExtCstm.sad_provincialmanager_c = ProvincialArea.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.RegionalArea AS RegionalArea ON ConsultantUserExtCstm.sad_regionalmanager_c = RegionalArea.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.SalesArea AS SalesArea ON ConsultantUserExtCstm.sad_salesmanager_c = SalesArea.ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN CapcubedInternalDB.dbo.LeadsLink AS LeadsLink ON Application.ApplicationID = LeadsLink.GroupCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN suitecrmprod.dbo.leads AS SuiteLeads ON LeadsLink.LeadsID = SuiteLeads.ID

--Latest Bank Submission
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
                    bankSub.ApplicationID As BankSubAppID, bankSub.SubmissionDate,
                    bankSub.Bank, bankSub.RequiredLoanAmount,
                    bankSub.BankCode AS BankSubBankCode

                    FROM Import.OobaBankSubmission bankSub

                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Import.OobaBankSubmission later ON bankSub.ApplicationID = later.ApplicationID
                                    AND bankSub.SubmissionDate > later.SubmissionDate
                    WHERE later.applicationID IS NULL) AS BankSub ON Application.ApplicationID = BankSub.BankSubAppID

LEFT OUTER JOIN ccrep_calendar_cstm AS SubmissionDates ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),BankSub.SubmissionDate,101) = SubmissionDates.original_date_c

WHERE SubmissionDates.cc_date_c BETWEEN COALESCE(EOMONTH(@StartDate), '01/31/2016') AND COALESCE(@EndDate, GETDATE(), -1)
AND ConsultantUserExtCstm.consultantstatus_c NOT LIKE 2
                )
     SELECT *
            INTO #Rn
            FROM DATA
            WHERE rn = 1

                SELECT i.IntakeMonth, c.ProvManager, c.RegManager, c.AreaSalesManager, c.Consultant, COALESCE(#Rn.Unit, 0) AS Unit
                INTO #FillData
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IntakeMonth FROM #Rn) AS i
                        CROSS JOIN
                    (SELECT DISTINCT Consultant, ProvManager, RegManager, AreaSalesManager FROM #Rn) AS c
                LEFT OUTER JOIN #Rn ON #Rn.IntakeMonth = i.IntakeMonth AND #Rn.Consultant = c.Consultant
                ORDER BY Consultant, IntakeMonth

                SELECT 
                    IntakeMonth,
                    Consultant,
                    Unit,
                    SUM(Unit) OVER(PARTITION BY Consultant ORDER BY Consultant ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS agentfourmonthperiod

                FROM #FillData

                WHERE ('(All)' IN (@ProvincialManager) OR (ProvManager IN (@ProvincialManager)))
                    AND ('(All)' IN (@RegionalManager) OR (RegManager IN (@RegionalManager)))
                    AND ('(All)' IN (@AreaSalesManager) OR (AreaSalesManager IN (@AreaSalesManager)))
                    AND ('(All)' IN (@Consultant) OR (Consultant IN (@Consultant)))

                DROP TABLE #Rn
                DROP TABLE #FillData
```

Comment: Show us some sample data and desired output.

Comment: If your original code is really long, can you simplify it just enough code to illustrate your question?   I would say that currently your question is too vague to answer.   We need to see an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Calculated fields are table properties. cannot be changed by queries.. i believe you meant you have a subquery in your main query am i right?

Comment: Yes I do have one in the main query. I have added the main query as well.

Comment: Remove the **date filter** (`SubmissionDates.cc_date_c BETWEEN COALESCE(EOMONTH(@StartDate), '01/31/2016') AND COALESCE(@EndDate, GETDATE(), -1)`) from your query and put it in the dataset of the report. This will let the query run with all the data to populate the window function. Then you filter out later for the dates you want. **OR** you can put the results from the last query in another TEMP table and then SELECT * from it with the where clause with the date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course remove any filter on dates from the query and apply them directly in the tablix of your report. Obvously, this means that SQL Server has to return all the data each time the report is run, so I guess that this isn't what you want.

For the window function to have access to the previous 3 rows, you will have to include the previous 3 months in your calculation. To achieve this, change the first condition in the WHERE clause in the cte (`data`) to something like this:

```
SubmissionDates.cc_date_c 
BETWEEN 
  ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @StartDate)-3, 0), '01/10/2015')
AND
  ISNULL(@EndDate, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0))
```

> As I thought that your date filter logic was wrong, I changed it to include the dates from the **beginning** of the month rather than from the **end**.

Now that the previous 3 months are included, we can apply a filter in the end to exclude the previous months from display, but this has to be done **after** using the window function, for example with another cte:

```
WITH calc AS (
    SELECT 
        IntakeMonth,
        Consultant,
        Unit,
        SUM(Unit) OVER(PARTITION BY Consultant ORDER BY Consultant ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS agentfourmonthperiod

    FROM #FillData

    WHERE ('(All)' IN (@ProvincialManager) OR (ProvManager IN (@ProvincialManager)))
      AND ('(All)' IN (@RegionalManager) OR (RegManager IN (@RegionalManager)))
      AND ('(All)' IN (@AreaSalesManager) OR (AreaSalesManager IN (@AreaSalesManager)))
      AND ('(All)' IN (@Consultant) OR (Consultant IN (@Consultant)))
    )

SELECT IntakeMonth, Consultant, Unit, agentfourmonthperiod
FROM calc 
WHERE IntakeMonth >= ISNULL(EOMONTH(@StartDate), '01/31/2016')
```

Comment: Awesome.. That worked perfectly :) I appreciate your help